# IE stop script warning

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Only in IE I get a warning when loading my site containing javascript saying that its causing the page to run slowly (and asking if I want to stop it).

I've seen other posts about this and I've looked for any long running code or infinite loops etc.  The weird thing is, when I select 'No' (to *not* terminate the script) the page immediately loads properly.  Its almost like this warning comes up right before the page is done loading.  Has anybody experienced this, or know why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the code doing on the page? Details are always good.

Answer (score 1):

IE has its own way of making your life impossible.

Just deactivate the warning, you can further research in the future if that's necessary.

This [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/) might help you determine why IE is giving such a warning.

Regards,

Comment: how do I deactivate the warning? I remember seeing something about using a registery setting to disable it on your machine. But how could I disable it for anybody accessign the site?

Comment: http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Get-Rid-of-the-JavaScript-Warning-on-Internet-Explorer&id=3555098  this might help

Comment: that is for turning it off on your browser..not for disabling it from ever happening on any client.  I think I should probably get to the source of the warning rather than disabling it.  Thanks though.

Comment: There is no "turn off" switch to get rid of this message programmatically, as the article explains, every browser has its own way of determining when a given script is taking too long to execute. In the case of IE, it uses the number of JS statements executed, so, you might want to check and refactor your code, probably is doing too much. If you find a way to disabling this transparently in all browsers I'll be glad to know how you did it. You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406739/Preventing-Stop-running-this-script-in-Browsers

```
// Magic IE<9 workaround for irritating "Stop running this script?" dialog.
RepeatOperation = function(anonymousOperation, whenToYield){
    var count = 0
    return function(){
        if (++count >= whenToYield){
            count = 0
            setTimeout(function(){anonymousOperation()}, 100)
        }
        else anonymousOperation()
    }
}

// How to implement the workaround:

//for (var i in retailers){ // Too big for IE<9! Use magic workaround:
var i = 0; var noInArray = retailers.length
var ro = new RepeatOperation(function(){

    // <<Your loop body here, using return instead of continue.>>

    if (++i < noInArray) ro()
    else alert("Loop finished.")
}, 200) // Run this in batches of n. 500 is too much for IE<9.
ro()
```